# how to filter dates that go from 10 -14 pm but not later by minutes in mysql?

Tags: mysql, datetime

```
 select * 
   from trip 
  where hour(time(time_out)) >=10 
   and hour(time(time_out)) <=14 
   and if ( hour(time(time_out)) == 14
```

But the 14:30 is later than 14:00

```
1900-01-01T14:30:00.000Z # this one should be excluded
1900-01-01T12:35:00.000Z
1900-01-01T12:00:00.000Z
1900-01-01T14:00:00.000Z
```

HOw to exclude it?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, how to get rid of 14:30 but keep others

Comment: Well you have to also test the minutes, because 14:01 does match the `hour(time(time_out)) <=14`

Comment: @RiggsFolly, yes, so how to exclude them - those later than 14 pm?

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE TIME(time_out) >= '10:00:00' AND TIME(time_out) <= '14:00:00'
```

Or even more concise:

```
WHERE TIME(time_out) BETWEEN '10:00:00' AND '14:00:00'
```